# Sql query to derive a column value based on the entry in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **person** table with fields `id`, `email`.

And a **subscription** table with fields: `person_id`, `category_id`.

If a person is subscribed **subscription** table will have at-least one entry in the table.

I want to query **person** table with the 3rd column having 1 or 0 depending on whether person is subscribed or not.

```
select p.id, p.email , [is_subscribed] 
from person p
```

`is_subscribed` should be 1 if there is an entry in the **subscription** table else should be 0.

How can I achieve the above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a LEFT JOIN on subscription & a count (in a case of several subscriptions)

```
SELECT p.id,p.email,IF(COUNT(s.category_id)>0,1,0) as is_subscribed
FROM
person as p
LEFT JOIN subscription as s ON s.person_id=p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   select distinct p.id, p.email, ifnull(sign(subscription.id),0) as is_subscribed
   from
       person
           left join subscriptions
           on person.id = subscriptions.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.`id` , p.`email` , IF(COUNT(s.`id`)>0,1,0) AS count
FROM  `person` p
LEFT JOIN  `subscription` s ON s.`person_id` = p.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct person.id, person.email, cast((select count(id) from sub where id=1) as bit) from tab, sub where tab.id=1;`

This is an MS SQL server query. Make necessary changes for mysql.